# Can't change UserAgent in UIWebview after loading page

Tags: ios, uiwebview

My IOS app has several UIWebView's in it.  From time-to-time, the user may needs to change from a mobile site to a desktop site of any given URL.  I'm using spoofing to do this by changing the UserAgent:

```
 + (void) startSpoofingUserAgent
 {
     [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:@{ @"UserAgent" : @"Desktop" }];
     [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
 }
```

I also have a method that kills the spoofing:

```
 + (void)stopSpoofingUserAgent
 {
      NSDictionary *registeredDefaults = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] volatileDomainForName:NSRegistrationDomain];
      if ([registeredDefaults objectForKey:@"UserAgent"] != nil)
      {
          NSMutableDictionary *mutableCopy = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:registeredDefaults];
          [mutableCopy removeObjectForKey:@"UserAgent"];
          [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setVolatileDomain:mutableCopy forName:NSRegistrationDomain];
          [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
      }
}
```

I then give the user the ability to change from desktop-to-mobile and mobile-to-desktop with a button.  I then reload the URL with this code:

```
        self.webView.delegate = self;
        self.webView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
        self.webView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;

        //Create a URL object.
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:self.convertedURL];

        //URL Request Object
        if(self.defaultToDesktopSite)
        {
            [MINNetworkingUtils startSpoofingUserAgent];
        }
        else
        {
            [MINNetworkingUtils stopSpoofingUserAgent];
        }

        NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

        //Load the request in the UIWebView.
        [self.webView loadRequest:requestObj];
```

I also buffer the current state the user has the UIWebView in so that it retains the setting across instances.  The first time the app runs, it works great regardless of which state it's in (Desktop or Mobile).

THE PROBLEM:
The problem is that I cannot change the state and have that reflected in the app AFTER the initial load.

Scenario 1:

- User runs app
- UIWebView is set to spoof UserAgent, thereby forcing the UIWebView to load the desktop site
- WORKS GREAT!

Scenario 2:

- User runs app
- UIWebView is set to NOT spoof UserAgent, thereby letting the UIWebView load a mobile site if it's available
- WORKS GREAT!

Scenario 3:

- User runs app
- UIWebView is set to spoof UserAgent
- Site comes up with Desktop site (as expected)
- User changes the state to "Mobile" by selecting button
- The app reloads the UIWebView using the code above (which UN-spoofs the connection)
- DOESN'T WORK
- The UIWebView reloads but it's still using the "Desktop" site and NOT the mobile site
- (THIS SCENARIO works the same way if reversed.  In other words, if the UIWebView is supposed to come us as "Mobile" the first time.  It works until I try to change it and reload it.)

Scenario 4:

- Go through the same steps as Scenario 3 BUT unload the app from memory and reload the app
- Since I journal the state, when the app comes up, the UIWebView thinks it's supposed to come up in "Mobile" mode (because the user changed it when they ran the app last time).
- IT WORKS AGAIN! The UIWebView comes up in "Mobile" mode.

What seems to be happening, is that the UIWebView is buffering something somewhere and won't allow me to reload the UIWebView with a different spoofing.  If the app is unloaded and reloaded, UIWebView works as expected.

I have tried to the following things to force the UIWebView to NOT buffer anything and have had no success:

```
 [[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeAllCachedResponses];
 ... reload URL

  self.convertedPageURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@?t=%@", self.convertedPageURL, randomString];
  ... reload URL
```

Like I said, I can't get the UIWebView to change from Desktop-to-Mobile or Mobile-to-Desktop WITHOUT unloading the app and reloading it.

HELP!!!

EDIT

This is the code that I was using to get the current value.  Once I've called this line of code, I can no longer change the UserAgent:

```
         defaultUserAgentString = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"navigator.userAgent"];
```

Comment: Have you tried this just in the simulator, or on a device as well? [This comment from a couple years ago](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15098321/change-user-agent-multiple-times#comment22259454_15098321) suggests that it might be just a simulator limitation.

Comment: Site might have placed a cookie or it might be a caching issue. Also it may depend on how the site is programed. Have you test with different sites and get the same results?

Comment: I can confirm that this issue exists, and my only answer would be: "File a radar".

Comment: Santa is right, it is a problem and it's not unique to the simulator.  I have tested it on several Apple devices with the same results.  I have also tested it with several sights so it's something to do with IOS.  I agree that it must be caching something somewhere but I'm unable to figure out a way to clear whatever that cache is.

Comment: Can you post the code that reads the useragent value from `NSUserDefaults`?

Comment: I just added an edit that shows what I think you're asking for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `UserAgent` user-defaults key is private API. It therefore has no guaranteed behaviour. All answers will be empirical.

That being said, it sounds like the correct solution is to kill and recreate your `UIWebView` following each change. `UIView` doesn't conform to `NSCopying` so you'll need to do something manual such as:

```
UIWebView *newWebView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.webView.frame];
newWebView.delegate = self;
newWebView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
// ... and the autoreseizing mask, etc — no need to do this upon every load

[self.webView.superview insertSubview:newWebView aboveSubview:self.webView];
[self.webView removeFromSuperview];
self.webView = newWebView;
```

---

If that fails to work, you probably need to switch to a documented means of setting the user agent. I'd suggest implementing your own `NSURLProtocol` handler that accepts `http` and `https` requests it hasn't yet seen, modifies the header field and dispatches them a second time, that time declining to take them so that they drop down to the system. It'll be hassle but it'll allow you to change that, or any other header field, reliably and with immediate effect.

See [kifi's engineering blog](http://eng.kifi.com/customizing-uiwebview-requests-with-nsurlprotocol/) for an example.